# iOS: correctly adopting a view into an already-visible parent

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have the following code to adopt a child view controller into a parent:

```
public static void AdoptViewController(this UIViewController parent, UIViewController child)
{
    parent.AddChildViewController(child);
    parent.View.AddSubview(child.View);
    child.DidMoveToParentViewController(parent);
}
```

This mostly works fine, except when the parent view is already visible. In such cases, the child view controller does not receive a `ViewWillAppear` event. This is causing knock-on problems throughout my app.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710371/viewwillappear-is-not-called-when-add-child-controller-to-table-view-cell), which suggests doing this:

```
public static void AdoptViewController(this UIViewController parent, UIViewController child)
{
    parent.AddChildViewController(child);

    child.BeginAppearanceTransition(true, false);
    parent.View.AddSubview(child.View);
    child.EndAppearanceTransition();

    child.DidMoveToParentViewController(parent);
}
```

However, that causes the `ViewWillAppear` event to be raised twice in the case where the parent is not yet visible. I re-worked the code a bit to this:

```
public static void AdoptViewController(this UIViewController parent, UIViewController child)
{
    parent.AddChildViewController(child);

    // could also use ViewIfLoaded for later iOS versions
    var parentAlreadyVisible = parent.IsViewLoaded && parent.Window != null;

    if (parentAlreadyVisible)
    {
        child.BeginAppearanceTransition(true, false);
    }

    parent.View.AddSubview(child.View);

    if (parentAlreadyVisible)
    {
        child.EndAppearanceTransition();
    }

    child.DidMoveToParentViewController(parent);
}
```

This appears to work mostly fine, except now my `ViewDidAppear` event is firing twice in the child view! The first time it is triggered by `EndAppearanceTransition`, and the second time appears to originate from iOS itself. This isn't actually causing me any problems, but it is disconcerting nonetheless.

**How do I write a standalone `AdoptViewController` utility method that correctly adopts a child view controller into a parent, and raises the right events the right number of times?**

Comment: on iOS 10.3 simulator your first variant is working for me. I am getting WillAppear on child. May be it depends on how you instantiate your child? I am getting it from storyboard

Comment: I'm sensing that you may be adding a new instance of the child view controller, you may not notice since you are applying the same layout to the view you are adding onto the screen. That was the first thing I accidentally did trying to write up the example. I accidentally instantiated two instances, which caused the calls to double up. Try putting a log statement into the method that is adding the child view controller, and see what happens. I made a gist as an example in swift https://gist.github.com/AntonTheDev/a1ae562234c55e451b885b16871318ac

Comment: @AntonTheDev Thanks for the suggestion. However, I just checked and there's definitely only the one instance of the child created.

Comment: @KentBoogaart try putting a print statement in the root class, could potentially be a memory leak too